# Implementing a Search Engine in a WPF Desktop Application

Tags: wpf, search, lucene, google-search-appliance

I'm looking at implementing a custom search functionality within a WPF desktop application that needs to be able to function while offline and online.

Are there any viable technologies that would allow this? Google Search Appliance, Lucene, etc.?

Comment: what do you want to search for? internet, tags, database data, etc?

Comment: Apologies, I would like to search through a custom relational database, and through documents on the local file system.